# How do I left align asp.net labels to footer when using bootstrap

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

The below asp.net WebForm code under a master page with bootstrap is for a small page of only 2 input boxes with labels. What I am trying to do is have the labels left aligned to the footer.  The way it is now, the labels are automatically indented so they are not lining up with the left edge of the footer.  On the second label and input box I tried setting the padding to 0px but that does not work well.

I also tried adding right margins to the divs by guessing how much to push the content to the left but that was also inconsistent.  I then tried the bootstrap statement "pull-left" which did make them move all the way to the left but my two word labels end up on top of each other when I do that.  Is there a way to make the labels left align so they match the left edge of the footer and retain the format of a label followed by associated input box all on one line? Thanks in advance.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JSFormValidate01.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormJSValidateForm.WebFormJSValidateForm01" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <br />
    <div class="form-horizontal row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="FirstNameTextBox" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Text="First Name:"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextBox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <asp:Label ID="FirstNameErrorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-horizontal row">
        <div class="form-group">

            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="LastNameTextBox" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" style="padding-right:0px" Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="server" style="padding-left:0px"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <asp:Label ID="LastNameErrorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Below is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Replace your `<asp:TextBox>` with `<input type="text" runat="server">` (i.e. use `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl` instead of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`) because it will give you more control over the rendered markup. Also, please post your **rendered HTML** when diagnosing CSS styling issues, not the ASPX server-side markup.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap itself have alignment classes, which you can use.

Add to class attribute: text-left

For more reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to nest the bootstrap grid so there are 24 columns to work with rather than 12. Also, the extra columns remove the need to use the "form-horizontal" class attribute to get the label closer to the textbox.  With more columns it is easier to position the labels and textboxes where they are needed. No extra bootstrap alignment classes were needed or switching to html5 tags rather than asp tags. The labels and textboxes now automatically adjust as expected for a responsive web page as the page is sized and the labels for both textboxes are always lined up on the left edge of the page matching the footer left edge.

Below is the solution:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JSFormValidate01.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormJSValidateForm.WebFormJSValidateForm01" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                     <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="FirstNameTextBox" CssClass="control-label" Text="First Name:"/>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextBox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="FirstNameErrorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="control-label"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                     <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="LastNameTextBox" CssClass="control-label" Text="Last Name:"/>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="LastNameErrorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="control-label"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Below is how the page now looks with the labels lined up to the footer left edge even as the page responds to different sizes and auto adjustments to labels and text boxes:

[image]